# "Domain Type" and other options not showing

Tags: fluid-simulation

(new to blender) I'm trying to change my domain type from smoke to gas, however my smoke domain settings are completely different from the tutorial I'm watching and I'm not sure how to change them.

[image: my settings] [image: tutorial's settings]

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? This option is available in Blender 2.90

Comment: I am using version 2.81

Comment: 2.8X uses the old fluid simulation, you need to download 2.90 to have the new options

Comment: I just updated my version and it's working now, thanks

Comment: @Emir This site is no regular forum rather a Q&A site. Please do not add solved to the title, either **upvote one of the existing answers**, add a new one which can be accepted or propose it as duplicate if you find another q and a. Please read about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

Fluid/Smoke settings have changed depending on the version of the Blender.

If your smoke/fluid settings are different than a tutorial, get the exact version, the tutorial is using.

You can download **any** (even the oldest) version of Blender on [their download page](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/).